# Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS "Checking battery state... [OK]" and login incorrect

Tags: 12.04, boot, nvidia, plymouth

I have quite a famous problem as it seems: while booting, the computer displays `Checking battery state... [OK]` and then hangs.

```
* Starting CUPS printing spooler/server
mountall: Plymouth copmmand failed
mountall: Disconnected from Plymouth
[...]
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
JMX enable by default
[...]
* Starting NTP server ntpd [ OK ]
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
* Checking battery state... [ OK ]
```

All the answers I could find mention pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and entering my credentials. But after doing so, I just get as an answer `login incorrect` and I'm again prompted to enter my credentials. I am 200% sure about my credentials, I have been working on this machine for over 3 weeks logging in and out around 10 times a day.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that on the command line you have the default keyboard driver, thus some keys may be different from waht you are used to.

Try the name field to look if the characters are how you need them.

Comment: I believe I tried this and the password was being displayed just fine. But it has been quite a while now, I reinstalled Ubuntu to "solve" the problem. Thank you for your contribution!